# Palindrome but with a scentence

Tags: c++, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

So writing a palindrome with pointers and boolean. I have it working with a single word but then I began building it to work with a sentence. The problem is I am unsure how to keep the new modified sentence after making it lowercase and getting rid of the spaces for it to return whether it is or isn't a palindrome. It keeps returning the palindrome as false and when I went to check why I see that the program ignores the modification and kept the original string. I can't use "&" on the parameter as I tested it out. Any hints or takes on what I can do to keep the new modified string?

```
int main()
{
    userInput();
    return 0;
}

void userInput()
{
    char str[90];

    std::cout<<"Please enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:  ";
    std::cin.getline(str, 90);

    modifyString(str);
}

void modifyString(char *string)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
    {
        putchar(tolower(string[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] != ' ')
        {
            string[count++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    string[count] = '\0';

    std::cout<<string<<std::endl;

    results(string);
}

bool checkPalindrome(char *string)
{
    char *begin;
    char *end;

    begin = string;
    end = (string + strlen(string)-1);

    while(begin != end)
    {
        if ((*begin) == (*end))
        {
            begin ++;
            end--;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
void results(char *string)
{
    bool isItPalindrome;

    isItPalindrome = checkPalindrome(string);

    if( isItPalindrome == true)
    {
        std::cout<<"\nCongrats, the string is a palindrome!";
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout<<"\nThis string is not a palindrome.";
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(begin != end)` If the length is even, this won't ever be true. You could use `for (int i = 0, j = strlen(string)-1; i < j; i++, j--) { if (string[i] != string[j]) return false; }`

Comment: better don't name a c-string `string`, it can cause confusion. At least you don't `using namespace std;`. Why do you not use `std::string` ?

Comment: `putchar(tolower(string[i]));` Just prints the string in lowercase, it does not modify the string.

Comment: Oh my professor kind of made us use the cstring for now for this project.

okay I see I will change that code then, yeah it always prints it out but when I take the space out it keeps it lowercase as well so thought it was modified. Will try what you said for my while loop and for loop

Comment: Oh and I was told to use the while loop so will this work instead of my original while loop that used bool in it? I used this and works the same as I had it. ```while(begin < end)``` but I change my for loop and works better than I did it though. So thank you for that info! :D

Answer (score 1):

For starters this definition of main

```
int main()
{
    userInput();
    return 0;
}
```

does not make a sense. According to the function name `main` the function should perform the main task that is to output whether the entered sentence is a palindrome or not.

This for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
{
    putchar(tolower(string[i]));
}
```

does nothing useful. It just outputs the string in the lower case.

This statement

```
end = (string + strlen(string)-1);
```

can invoke undefined behavior if an empty string was passed.

This while loop

```
while(begin != end)
{
    if ((*begin) == (*end))
    {
        begin ++;
        end--;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

also can invoke undefined behavior for a string containing an even number ofo characters because after this if statement

```
    if ((*begin) == (*end))
    {
        begin ++;
        end--;
    }
```

if the two adjacent characters are equal then `begin` after incrementing will be greater than `end` after its decrementing. And as a result the loop will continue its iteration.

In general the approach when the original string is changed is just a bad approach.
Your program has too many functions. It is enough to write one function that will determine whether the passed string is a palindrome or not.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

bool checkPalindrome( const char *s )
{
    const char *t = s + std::strlen( s );
    
    do
    {
        while ( s != t && std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++ s;
        while ( s != t && std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*--t ) );
    } while ( s != t && 
              std::tolower( ( unsigned char )*s ) == tolower( ( unsigned char ) *t ) &&
              ++s != t );
    
    return s == t;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s[N] = "";

    std::cout << "Please enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:  ";
    std::cin.getline( s, N );
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    if ( checkPalindrome( s ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Congrats, the string is a palindrome!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "This string is not a palindrome.\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Please enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:  1 23 456 6 54 321

Congrats, the string is a palindrome!
```

Comment: I see and yeah my professor wants us to avoid using the main that much and have everything in different functions, so have it invoked in the main and that is it. I see what you are doing and is actually better. I think I have a better understanding on what you did in your code. Thank you for input and help. Now I can make my code even better.

Comment: @VictorCano You can place in main a call for inputting string, then a call of the function that removes blanks and then the if-ekse statement. In this case it will be seen what the program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it!

As one of the users on here brought up a point that my lowercase did not modify the string and only prints it out. I try my best to solve the problem and I think I found the solution and everything works perfectly fine. comment back to debug it if you like to see how it looks but what I did was create a for loop again for the lower case but made another pointer with it. here how it looks.

```
for (char *pt = string; *pt != '\0'; ++pt)
    {
        *pt = std::tolower(*pt);
        ++pt;
    }
```

Now that definitely changes the string into a lower case and keeps it as a lower case.

so now the modified function looks like this and ready to take any sentence palindrome you give it. Example: A nUt fOr a jAr of tUNa. We make this all lowercase and take out space and boom palindrome and return true.

```
void modifyString(char *string)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (char *pt = string; *pt != '\0'; ++pt)
    {
        *pt = std::tolower(*pt);
        ++pt;
    }

    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] != ' ')
        {
            string[count++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    string[count] = '\0';

//take out the forward slash below to see how it looks after being modified
//    std::cout<<std::endl<<string<<std::endl;

    results(string);
}
```

Comment: For future readers, you can accept the answer if it solved your issue.